# Automated Import of .txt files into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

How do I set up an automated import of .txt files from a folder into a MySQL Database?

Also, I would like each text file imported to be in a table of its own; for example importing "john.txt" creates a table called john and importing john2.txt creates a table called john2.

The text files are named in a format of "COMPUTERNAME-DATE.txt" and are stored in "C:\inetpub\FTP Logs Folder" in my PC.

Comment: I have tried this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,155114,155141   but this is manual importing.

Comment: So whenever someone uploads a new file to your PC, it should automatically be imported?

Comment: @Simon yes, whenever a new .txt file is uploaded to "C:\inetpub\FTP Logs Folder" I would want it to be automatically imported to database. Each uploaded .txt should have its own table. Is that possible?

Comment: Certainly, but due to my lacking Windows know how I can only suggest an abstract solution: You need something that notifies you about changes in the upload directory. On the Mac, we have file system notifications. Then you need that mechanism to trigger a script (which you can write in your favourite language) which takes the new file's name as an input, renders the appropriate `CREATE TABLE` / `LOAD DATA` statements and runs them with MySQL. It looks like quite a bit of work, but maybe someone else knows a tool or two tp simplify things?

Comment: I just stumbled upon the MySQL event scheduler: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html . It's basically a builtin task scheduler to run stored procedures. You could use that instead of file system notifications to check for new files periodically. I'm not sure whether you can do the whole import from a stored procedure, though.

Comment: if you know how to import manually for that, create a windows batch file with that code and schedule it on your given date/time.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do it is write your own importer and put it into somekind of Window CRON (is there something similar?).